# Possible to switch between flash and IOS component?

Tags: ios, flash

I have a website that uses flash.
Is it possible to do something like this

pseudo code

```
if (user_agent == iOS[ipad, iphone, what-have-you])
    show_ios_component
else
    show_flash_component
```

My question is thus: is there a way to build "apps" that run on websites.
I see this all the time for video sites like YouTube, MSNBC etc i.e. that their video player all of a sudden works in iOS browsers like safari and chrome run on iPad, iPhone etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flash won't run on IOS. An app that runs on a website is in this case an .swf(Flash). Those sites use a HTML5 fallback for the videos, so you will have determin in the browser which OS the target has, and then either show the swf or HTML5 component. One usually does that in javascript

```
var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
```

this snippet will tell you if IOS is true or false.

Comment: ok, so it's HTML5 that they use. Well, that sort of kills it for me since I have games in SWF that is being displayed (and played :)

Comment: You could deploy it as an ios app with air, and offer that if an ios User comes along